# Django query filter with contains and empty list variable

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

`matched = Details.objects.filter(Q(cnp=cnp) | Q(phones__contains=[phone]) | Q(emails__contains=[email])).values('id')`

```
class Details(models.Model):

    ...
    cnp = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    phones = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), size=20, blank=True, default=list)
    emails = ArrayField(models.EmailField(), size=20, blank=True, default=list)
```

Hello!

I want to make a query and if any of the fields(cnp,phones or emails) have a match to get the result queryset.
The cnp, phone and email variable will get just one value that I need to match with one or more values from the ArrayField.
I made the query above using Q but the problem is that I can have empty list/string for phone or email variable and then that matches all my database.
If i don't use 'contains', I can match single valued lists(from the db ArrayField) but for example if I have multiple emails in the db I need to match it with 'contains' to get a result.
Is this possible only from a django query?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like other objects which support using the `|` bitwise operator Django Q objects we can also use `|=` assignment, which might help in this case.

```py
queries = Q(cnp=cnp)

if phone:
    queries |= Q(phones__contains=[phone])
if email:
    queries |= Q(emails__contains=[email])

matched = Details.objects.filter(queries)
```

This should allow you to perform a check on `phone` or `email` and only include those values in the Q object passed to the queryset if they are approved.